# How to get the matched values from an array to another array via (NODE.JS);

Tags: javascript, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I'm new to JSCRIPT and I would like to try the twitter sentiment analysis. I have an array1 named "disectToWords" where the sentiments are located. Then, I have another array called "getScoredWords" where the "AFINN.txt" or "the scores of words" is located. I want to match both of arrays, to get the matched values. I'm trying to use filter(), however, I always got a null/empty array which means, all are false.

```
var getScoredWords = ['abandon',
  'abandoned',
  'abandons',
  'abducted',
  'abduction',
  'abductions',
  'abhor',
  'abhorred',
  'abhorrent',
  'abhors',
  'abilities',
  'ability',
  'aboard',
  'absentee',]

var disectToWords = ['Barry',
    'Manilow',
    'Singin',
    'With',
    'The',
    'Big',
    'Bands',
    'abducted',
    'aboard',]

var result = getScoredWords.filter(words => disectToWords.includes(words));
```

but it should return the word 'abducted' and 'aboard'.
please help

Comment: Remove the quotes around variable name, except that your code is fine,  [`working demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/6nx0kwbm/)

Answer (score 0):

Hello I am trying this its look fine So you can try

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var getScoredWords = ['abandon',
      'abandoned',
      'abandons',
      'abducted',
      'abduction',
      'abductions',
      'abhor',
      'abhorred',
      'abhorrent',
      'abhors',
      'abilities',
      'ability',
      'aboard',
      'absentee',]

    var disectToWords = ['Barry',
        'Manilow',
        'Singin',
        'With',
        'The',
        'Big',
        'Bands',
        'abducted',
        'aboard',]

    var result = getScoredWords.filter(words => disectToWords.includes(words));
    console.log(result);
    </script>
```

Comment: Btw, I'm doing this via node.js in terminal for (MAC) or Cprompt(Win). I think alert() won't run on terminal. But, Thanks!